# Match a specific string in Python except if it a given pattern is missing

Tags: python, regex

This question might have already been asked, but I have found any solution so far.

I want to match strings that contain `inhibition(.+)toxicity` but I do not want to match `growth inhibition(.+)toxicity`.

I tried `(!?growth )inhibition(.+)toxicity` but it returns the string I want to exclude. However, using `(!?growth)` returns everything except the strings containing growth.

I do not understand what I am doing wrong with this regex.

EDIT: add example

string I want to mach: `Inhibition of recombinant human TNF-alpha-induced cytotoxicity of mouse L929 cells`

string I do not want to match: `Evaluated for the inhibitory concentration required to cause growth inhibition of A427Mer- cell line of lung using the MTT Cytotoxicity Assay`

Comment: Use a negative lookbehind: `r'(?<!growth )inhibition(.+)toxicity'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error. The correct regex is:

```
(?<!growth )inhibition(.+)toxicity
```

Take a look at [Regex Tutorial - Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: The regex you and anubhava provides does not return anything. I realise it may due to the strings I want or don't want to match. I have edited my initial question with a real case example.

Comment: It works indeed ([see demo](https://regex101.com/r/cwHhTh/1)). Remember to use the `i` modifier, i.e. the case-insensitive flag.

Comment: Yes it woks in your demo I agree. I use the regex with Pandas (function str.contains) and the case argument is set to False.